# Are C2DMBaseReceiver & C2DMBroadcastReceiver needed anymore?

Tags: java, android

I've seen these classes in a few projects and was wondering if they are needed anymore for push notifications:

https://github.com/casidiablo/c2dm-library/tree/master/src/main/java/com/google/android/c2dm

- C2DMBaseReceiver.java
- C2DMBroadcastReceiver.java
- C2DMessaging.java

I've read a few tutorials online and these seem like helpers for Google's old push notification system, Cloud 2 Device. This has now been replaced with GCM, so are these classes needed at all anymore?

Also if C2DM has been already deprecated and deemed obsolete, and as seen [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/c2dm), shut down as of late 2015, how can these applications still operate with push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

The only references left from C2DM are the `permissions` and `actions`

```
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND
com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
```

for example so no those specific classes are not used anymore and replaced with classes like `GcmReceiver` and`GcmListenerService`

weather those applications/example are still able to get messages I don't know, I didn't wait to find out and changed all my stuff over from C2DM